# Using imagesc to show the relation between IPR VS ( \sigma vs E), problem with matrix

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, vector, physics

I calculated the IPR for quantum system. this resulted in an N x 1 vector.
For this IPR there is the related eigenstates and eigenvalues, so we have another the vector for the eigenvalues E, and there is the $/sigma$ values.
So there is different E & IPR vectors for each sigma.
In the end we have the IPR Matrix (vector matrix for different sigma values), and E matrix (vector matrix for different sigma values) and the vector sigma.
 imagesc takes (vector,vector,matrix) or imagesc(E,sigma,IPR). but there is a problem, because E isn't a vector anymore. 
 how do I solve this? or did I just not understand the imagesc command? the code is below.
I flatten E to try and solve this, but I dont know if this is the right solution.

```
z = ones(N-1,1);
c = 1;
ranNum = diag(rand([N 1]));
Nsig = 10^2;
sigma = ones(Nsig,1).';
E = ones(Nsig,N);
IPR = ones(Nsig,N);

for j = 1:Nsig
    sigma(j) = 0.01 + 0.01*(j-1);
    H1 = c*(diag(z,1)+ diag(z,-1) + diag(1,N-1)+ diag(1,-N+1));
    V1 = sigma(j) * ranNum ;
    H = H1 + V1;
    [psi,~] = eig(H);
    E(j,:) = eig(H);
    P1 = abs(psi).^2;
    IPR(j,:) = sum(P1.^2);
    if j == 1
        E_try = E(1,:);
    end
    if j>1
        E_try = [E_try E(j,:)];
    end
end





imagesc(E_try,sigma,IPR)
colormap('turbo')
colorbar
xlabel('E')
ylabel('sigma')
h = colorbar;
ylabel(h, 'IPR')
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to solve this trying to use the following code? creating the imagesc layer by layer?

```
N = 2^9;
z = ones(N-1,1);
c = 1;
ranNum = diag(rand([N 1]));
Nsig = 10^2;
sigma = ones(Nsig,1).';
E = ones(Nsig,N);
E2 = ones(Nsig,N);
E3 = ones(Nsig,N);
IPR = ones(Nsig,N);

for j = 1:Nsig
    sigma(j) = 0.01 + 0.01*(j-1);
    H1 = c*(diag(z,1)+ diag(z,-1) + diag(1,N-1)+ diag(1,-N+1));
    V1 = sigma(j) * ranNum ;
    H = H1 + V1;
    [psi,~] = eig(H);
    E(j,:) = eig(H);
    P1 = abs(psi).^2;
    IPR(j,:) = sum(P1.^2);
    
    imagesc(E(j,:),sigma(j),IPR(j,:))
    colormap('turbo')
    colorbar
    xlabel('E')
    ylabel('sigma')
    h = colorbar;
    ylabel(h, 'IPR')
    hold on
    
end
```

also tryed to just take the maximum values of E and sigma but it doesnt show the shift in energy because the min and max values of E differ for different IPR vectors.

```
N = 2^9;
z = ones(N-1,1);
c = 1;
ranNum = diag(rand([N 1]));
Nsig = 10^2;
sigma = ones(Nsig,1).';
E = ones(Nsig,N);
E2 = ones(Nsig,1);
E3 = ones(Nsig,1);
IPR = ones(Nsig,N);

for j = 1:Nsig
    sigma(j) = 0.01 + 0.01*(j-1);
    H1 = c*(diag(z,1)+ diag(z,-1) + diag(1,N-1)+ diag(1,-N+1));
    V1 = sigma(j) * ranNum ;
    H = H1 + V1;
    [psi,~] = eig(H);
    E(j,:) = eig(H);
    P1 = abs(psi).^2;
    IPR(j,:) = sum(P1.^2);
    
    %{
    imagesc([max(E(j,:)) min(E(j,:))],sigma(j),IPR(j,:))
    colormap('turbo')
    colorbar
    xlabel('E')
    ylabel('sigma')
    h = colorbar;
    ylabel(h, 'IPR')
    hold on
    %}
    E2(j) = min(E(j,:));
    E3(j) = max(E(j,:));
end
E4 = [min(E2) max(E3)];
sig = [sigma(1) sigma(Nsig)];
imagesc(E4,sig,IPR)
colormap('turbo')
colorbar
xlabel('E')
ylabel('sigma')
h = colorbar;
ylabel(h, 'IPR')
```

Comment: This looks like more information about your question.  Please update your original question with this information. That should help you find someone who can answer you and help future readers understand easier.